# Financial excel if then statement

Tags: excel-formula

I am making a financial spread sheet for work but I have six categories for different options. I want to be able to put an X in a category and excel automatically be adding my totals. The numbers are set in the categories butthe situation changes.

Comment: show us some mock data, so we can better understand what you are looking for.

Comment: what you are talking about is very possible, but without something to follow, more details on layout, mock data, screen shots, its really hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a stab in the dark at a solution for you, see below the numbers represent the category's and the 0 is the cell the formula is in (G2).

[image: example]

If there is an X directly below the category, then the formula adds up the total of the column the X is in, and removes the category number from the total.

```
=IF(A3="X",SUM(A:A)-A2,IF(B3="X",SUM(B:B)-B2,IF(C3="X",SUM(C:C)-C2,IF(D3="X",SUM(D:D)
-D2,IF(E3="X",SUM(E:E)-E2,IF(F3="X",SUM(F:F)-F2,IF(G3="X",SUM(G:G)-G2,"")))))))
```

Is this any help?